# In SQL Server / Liquibase, does INSERT query create a table, automatically without CREATE schema, if it does not exist?

Tags: sql-server, insert, liquibase

I am using Liquibase for managing SQL Server scripts (create, update, delete, alters etc.).

My requirement was to create a backup table (say `old_table_a`) before I could drop two columns (`column_1`, `column_2`) from the original table (`table_a`).

The new backup table does not need a primary key, so it will just have two columns as shown below

**old_table_a**

1. column_1 (from original table_a)
2. column_2 (from original table_a)

If I just write `INSERT` query as shown below, without having a `CREATE TABLE old_table_a`

```
INSERT INTO old_table_a (column_1, column_2)
    SELECT column_1, column_2
    FROM table_a
```

I had read this somewhere on some blog, but cannot find this.

Please provide some information if this is possible.

Otherwise I know that the usual way to do this is to create the new backup table and then populate the new table with values from the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with SELECT * INTO:

```
SELECT * INTO [NEWTABLE] FROM [OLDTABLE]
```

Comment: Since the OP supplied column names and best practice suggests avoiding `select *` outside of a few specialised situations (of which this isn't one), why would you prefer `select *` here rather than `select column_1, column2`?

Comment: Select * is the best method to create a backup table. The only exception I can think of is wanting to exclude computed columns, but I'd like to hear why backing up is not one of the specialised situations. If the OP only selected the two columns, how would they ever link them back to the original table? At the very least the identifier(s) should be included. The questions over columns justify a '*' solution by itself that the OP can work from.

Comment: So you don't think lines like "The new backup table does not need a primary key, so it will just have two columns as shown below" indicates that the OP intends the new table to *only* contain those two columns?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I think there is confusion. As I said, how are two non-identifier columns ever of use by themselves? I don't understand and I think the OP may not have considered it. If someone is doing a full table backup (he calls it old_table_a suggesting it is a snapshot of table_a) then a '*' is good, otherwise, they can chose columns. Are you in agreement that Select * is good practice for whole table backups? I also used [NEWTABLE] and [OLDTABLE] because the OP's last sentences sounded like an appeal for knowledge rather than an exact answer.

Comment: I guess I have found my solution. All I wanted here is to backup the primary key (id) column from the original table along with another column in a new table. so I guess doing something like 
SELECT id as oldPrimaryKeyId, column_b INTO [NEWTABLE] FROM [OLDTABLE] 
works for my application

Answer (score -4):

INSERT tableName1 (ColumName)
 (select (ColumName ) from TableName2)

Comment: Please provide with some explanations, thank you.